# Where can I learn about open research topics in Bitcoin?

Tags: academic-research

I am currently doing my Master's Thesis, and I really want it to be about blockchain technology, and specifically Bitcoin. I was wondering if anyone here has any ideas on improvements or further research that may be needed or even well-needed on the topic blockchain or Bitcoin.

Comment: May I suggest speaking to potential supervisors on what they think? At the end of the day, you will be working with one, and therefore you want to pick a project that they can offer assistance with.

Comment: What discipline are your studies in? Answers are likely different depending on how you're approaching it, e.g. from a math, computer science, social science, etc., perspective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list is going to be very long so I'll point you to some resources instead.

Blockstream has a list of research areas and an archive of research papers [here](https://blockstream.com/research/). Similarly [Chaincode Labs](https://chaincode.com/research) and [BitMEX](https://blog.bitmex.com/research/).

There is a [repository](https://bitcoinproblems.org/) of open Bitcoin research problems and a [working group](https://github.com/ariard/bitcoin-contracting-primitives-wg) on Bitcoin Contracting Primitives.

You can also subscribe to the [bitcoin-dev](https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/mailman/listinfo/bitcoin-dev) and the [lightning-dev](https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/mailman/listinfo/lightning-dev) mailing lists that often discuss research topics.